# Extend the ContentFlow plugin : Click event, customize css and use Ul li instead of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

Has anyone worked with the contentFlow plugin? It seems interesting and I'm planing to use it in my application. So, I want to be precised about these:

- Does it trigger events when an item is clicked? if yes, how to use this event (to subscribe). I want to retrieve the clicked item object in an other jQuery plugin.
- Is it possible to use a Ul list as container?
- and finally, how to customize the style-sheet?

Comment: have you tried carroussel ?

Comment: Yes That's what I finally used. thank you for effort